# Decidability context-sensitiv and context-free grammars

Tags: logic, automata, context-free-grammar, decidability

Show that it is unsolvable whether a given context-sensitive language is context fre.

And, show that the emptiness problem is solvable for one-way nondeterministic stack automata.

I don't know how to use PCP for first one. And also, i have no idea for solution of secund one.